# DevArt MySql EF6 Drivers: Nullable BIT(1) columns have their null-value rows always evaluated to true for 'COLUMN_NAME ?? false'

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Libs employed:

```
  Devart.Data.dll => 5.0.1878.0
  Devart.Data.MySql.dll => 8.10.1086.0
  Devart.Data.MySql.Design.dll => 8.10.1086.0
  Devart.Data.MySql.Entity.EF6.dll => 8.10.1086.0
  EntityFramework => 6.2.0
```

We are targeting .net4.7.1 from an ASP.NET MVC5 project. Our repositories are build on top of an EF .edmx (db-first approach). Our queries look like so:

```
  var results = _db.NB_FILTERS
        .Select(x => new ReportFiltersDTO { IsHiddenSubFilter = x.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN ?? false })
        .ToList();
```

NFS_SUBFILTER_YN is declared as a boolean in our .edmx aka:

```
  <Property Name="NFS_SUBFILTER_YN" Type="boolean" />
```

The NB_FILTERS ddl is like so:

```
  CREATE TABLE NB_FILTERS (
        [...]
        NFS_SUBFILTER_YN BIT(1) NULL,
        [...]
  )
```

In such a scenario if certain rows are null the given linq expression returns 'true' for all of them instead of 'false'. The culprit appears to be in the auto-generated sql:

```
  actual => CASE WHEN Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN END

  corrected => CASE WHEN Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CAST(Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN AS SIGNED) END
```

How can one workaround this bug without changing en-masse the underlying tables and/or the linq statements themselves until an actual fix is rolled out by Devart?

Sidenotes:

- For those interested we've notified the devart devs about this issue in hopes that it will be addressed at some point:

  https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=36955
- Interestingly enough such queries work when the columns involved are nullable decimal(x,y) columns [the auto-generated sql correctly employs CAST(... AS SIGNED)]. It appears that somehow bit(x) was omitted from the list of types which are eligible for such handling.

Comment: why allow null value when it's a bit(1) type? By using/allowing null, you are allowing (3) true,false, unknown values where your application is required only (2) true/false. I would advise to modify your column & set as non null, default value = false. You don't need to deal with extra hassles.

Comment: Good point for sure. Unfortunately my team can't tweak the db at this point in time both due to time constraints and due to the fact that breakage might be induced in other parts/platforms hitting the same db. Just another typical day in the dev-land realm :(

Comment: Your problem and solution below reminds me of the first day at my uni and the "tree swing story" :) :)

Comment: What if you do `IsHiddenSubFilter = (bool?)x.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN ?? false`?

Comment: @GertArnold The x.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN is already declared as Nullable<bool> so the cast has no effect

Comment: Sure, but it may affect the generated SQL in a fortunate way.

Comment: @GertArnold I tested it too but no joy unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary stop-gap solution we opted to use an EF6 interceptor on mysql in order to detect and correct on-the-fly sql statements targeting boolean columns (thankfully most if not all all of our boolean columns have the _YN postfix which helps a great deal):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Some.Namespace
{
    //to future maintainers     the devart mysql drivers for ef6 ver8.10.1086.0 suffer from what appears to be a very annoying b.ug which cause nullable bit(1) columns set to null
    //to future maintainers     to always be materialized to true when we evaluate them like so
    //to future maintainers
    //to future maintainers                                                  x.SOME_BOOLEAN_COLUMN ?? false
    //to future maintainers
    //to future maintainers     this is obviously flat out wrong and to remedy this issue we intercept the offending sql snippets and hotfix them like so
    //to future maintainers    
    //to future maintainers                before => CASE WHEN Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN    IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE             Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN            END
    //to future maintainers                after  => CASE WHEN Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN    IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE     CAST(Extent1.NFS_SUBFILTER_YN AS SIGNED)    END
    //to future maintainers
    public sealed class MySqlHotFixerCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        //beforeexecution
        public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) => LogWarningBeforeExecutionIfSynchronousExecutionIsFound(command, interceptionContext);
        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) => LogWarningBeforeExecutionIfSynchronousExecutionIsFound(command, interceptionContext);
        public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) => LogWarningBeforeExecutionIfSynchronousExecutionIsFound(command, interceptionContext);

        //afterexecution
        public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) {}
        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) {}
        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) {}

        static private void LogWarningBeforeExecutionIfSynchronousExecutionIsFound<TResult>(IDbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
                return;

            command.CommandText = FaultySwitchCaseSpotter1.Replace(command.CommandText, "CAST($3 AS SIGNED)");
            command.CommandText = FaultySwitchCaseSpotter2.Replace(command.CommandText, "CAST($3 AS SIGNED)");
        }

        private static readonly Regex FaultySwitchCaseSpotter1 = new Regex(@"(?<=CASE\s+WHEN\s+(`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?[.])?`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?\s+IS\s+NULL\s+THEN\s+(0|1)\s+ELSE\s+)((`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?[.])?`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?)(?=\s*END)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        private static readonly Regex FaultySwitchCaseSpotter2 = new Regex(@"(?<=CASE\s+WHEN\s+(`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?[.])?`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?_YN`?\s+IS\s+NULL\s+THEN\s+(\d+|.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?|`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?[.]`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?)\s+ELSE\s+)((`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`?[.])?`?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?_YN`?)(?=\s*END)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

The web.config/app.config needs to be tweaked as well like so:

```
<configuration>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
       [...]
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <providers>
       [...]
    </providers>

    <interceptors>
      <!-- keep first -->
      <interceptor type="Some.Namespace.MySqlHotFixerCommandInterceptor, Organotiki.Infrastructure.Core">
      </interceptor>
      [...]
    </interceptors>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```